# How to protect a react route based on an iframe

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Currently I have a react router with an auth implementation. It works fine with simple component based routes.
This is my PrivateRoute component

```
import {  Route } from "react-router-dom";
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

    export default function PrivateRoute ({component: Component, authed, ...rest}) {
        return (
          <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => authed === true  
              ? <Component {...props} /> 
              : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: {from: props.location}}} />} 
          /> 
        )
      }
```

And those kinds of routes work properly with it

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute authed={this.state.isAuthenticated} path='/register' component={RegisterPage} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Problem happens with those kinds of routes, that do not have components

```
<Route path="/route1" render={(props) => <iframe frameBorder={0} src={constans.urlRoute1} className="iframe" />} />
```

This is my proposed solution to make it work as a private route, but the problem is that its missing the url redirect

```
<Route path="/route1" render={(props) => ((this.state.isAuthenticated) ? <iframe frameBorder={0} src={constans.urlRoute1} className="iframe" /> : <NewLandingPage {...props} /> )} />
```

So how to make the redirect work with iframe?

Comment: What do you mean? Why don't you render `<Redirect to={'whereever'} />` instead of `<NewLandingPage {...props} />`?

Comment: That actually does the trick @SagiRika , altho I will try to make it into some sort of protectediframeroute , just to make it cleaner

Comment: I editted my comment to include editted ProtectedRoute that will match both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting it as an answer in case someone stumbles upon it form Google:

```
<Route path="/route1" render={(props) => ((this.state.isAuthenticated) ? <iframe frameBorder={0} src={constans.urlRoute1} className="iframe" /> : <Redirect to='/my/link' /> )} />
```

I editted ProtectedRoute so it would work with the iframe too.

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

export default ({ component: Component, render: renderFn, authed, ...rest }) =>
  Component ? (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authed === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  ) : (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => authed === true ? () => renderFn(props) : () => <Redirect to="my/link" />} />
  );
```

And call the iFrame route like:

```
<Route authed={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/route1" render={props => <iframe frameBorder={0} src={constans.urlRoute1} className="iframe" />} />
```

Comment: Could you please let me know what did you tweak, so I could edit my answer accordingly?

Comment: I had to pass the authed state to the call of the iframe route ```<PrivateRoute authed={this.state.isAuthenticated} path="/route1" render={props => <iframe frameBorder={0} src={constans.route1} className="iframe" />} />```